# How to stop applet in Browser using Button that is built inside applet?

Tags: java, applet

I have written some line of java codes in **applet** and there is a **button called QUIT** , it's work is to terminate the execution but when applet runs in browser than it doesn't?

I have tried:

- `System.exit(1);`
- `System.exit(0);`
- Applet `destroy();`
- Applet `dispose();`

None of them work in browser what's the logic behind this?

Comment: Your applet is being run at the whim/mercy of the browser, it's not your decision to decide when the applet should be "destroyed", it's up to the browser.  Simple answer - Don't

Comment: But inside browser there is command or not ?

Comment: No, Applet has no concept of developer defined "exit", only the browser will destroy the applet when it decides it needs to be done...

Comment: Thanks than How to do this ? What should be modified in Applet code to do this work correctly .

Comment: The best choice you have is to "reset" the applet back to it's initial state...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `System.exit(1);`

That is for abnormal termination of an app.  It should not be used here, and not used in an application unless there is a fatal error from which it cannot recover.

- `System.exit(0);`

An applet might share a Java Virtual Machine with other applets.  If the applet in the JVM can be seen as a guest in a guesthouse, that is like one of the guests burning down the guesthouse!  It is not permitted even in an applet that is trusted.

- Applet `destroy();`

That method is called automatically by the JVM when the JVM thinks it is appropriate to do so.  An applet might override the method, but should not explicitly call it.

- Applet `dispose();`

Same deal as `destroy()`, leave it to the JVM.

---

The easiest way to end and applet is by using [`AppletContext.showDocument(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29).  It might work something like this (where `this` represents an `Applet`):

```
this.getAppletContext().showDocument(thanksForUsingOurAppletURL);
```

That will of course, redirect to the URL.  The JVM will call the `dispose()` and `destroy()` methods. Then when it decides it appropriate to do so, (which might be '30 seconds or so' after the last applet ends), it will shut itself down.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke JavaScript from the applet to rewrite the div containing the applet. That will do it! Using [JSObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html), so I might use [eval()](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/java/plugin2/liveconnect/jsobject-javadoc/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html#eval%28java.lang.String%29) with something like this

```
JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
win.eval("document.getElementById('#applet').innerHTML=''", null);
```

You might also use [getAppletContext().showDocument(goodbyeUrl)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29)